# WordPress - bootstrap parent and child category breadcrumbs

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a php function to display breadcrumbs, however it display wrong order

for **strong text** example

> Home / Child/ Parent / post

when it should be

> Home / Parent / Child / Posts

Why?

**Function**

```
function bavota_breadcrumbs() {
    if(!is_home()) {
        echo '<nav class="breadcrumb">';
        echo '<a href="'.home_url('/').'">'.get_bloginfo('name').'</a><span class="divider">/</span>';
        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            the_category(' <span class="divider">/</span> ');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo ' <span class="divider">/</span> ';
                the_title();
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            echo the_title();
        }
        echo '</nav>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `the_category(' <span class="divider">/</span>', 'multiple');`?

Comment: Can you please check my answer

Comment: sorry just got in, will check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try below code. do not use the_category display all category in which post assign to it. below function is show only it's parent category.

```
function bavota_breadcrumbs() {
    if(!is_home()) {
        echo '<nav class="breadcrumb">';
        echo '<a href="'.home_url('/').'">'.get_bloginfo('name').'</a><span class="divider">/</span>';
        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            //the_category(' <span class="divider">/</span> ');
            global $wp_query;
            $object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

            // Get parents of current category
            $parent_id  = $object->category_parent;
            $cat_breadcrumbs = '';
            while ($parent_id) {
                $category   = get_category($parent_id);
                echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->cat_ID) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>';
                $parent_id  = $category->category_parent;
                echo ' <span class="divider">/</span> ';
            }
            echo '<span>'.$object->cat_name.'</span>';

            if (is_single()) {
                echo ' <span class="divider">/</span> ';
                the_title();
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            echo the_title();
        }
        echo '</nav>';
    }
}
```

see the_category() function [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category)

**This code is tested and work perfect.**

Comment: hmm seems neat and readable but dose not print category and parent category, ill try and work with this. thanks

Comment: Hmm, I think ive fixed it, ill edit your answer soon to include a fix

Comment: what is remaining part?